# How can I add multiple should_receive expectations on an object using RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In my Rails controller, I'm creating multiple instances of the same model class.  I want to add some RSpec expectations so I can test that it is creating the correct number with the correct parameters.  So, here's what I have in my spec:

```
Bandmate.should_receive(:create).with(:band_id => @band.id, :user_id => @user.id, :position_id => 1, :is_leader => true)
Bandmate.should_receive(:create).with(:band_id => @band.id, :user_id => "2222", :position_id => 2)
Bandmate.should_receive(:create).with(:band_id => @band.id, :user_id => "3333", :position_id => 3)
Bandmate.should_receive(:create).with(:band_id => @band.id, :user_id => "4444", :position_id => 4)
```

This is causing problems because it seems that the Bandmate class can only have 1 "should_receive" expectation set on it.  So, when I run the example, I get the following error:

```
Spec::Mocks::MockExpectationError in 'BandsController should create all the bandmates when created'
Mock 'Class' expected :create with ({:band_id=>1014, :user_id=>999, :position_id=>1, :is_leader=>true}) but received it with ({:band_id=>1014, :user_id=>"2222", :position_id=>"2"})
```

Those are the correct parameters for the second call to create, but RSpec is testing against the wrong parameters.

Does anyone know how I can set up my should_receive expectations to allow multiple different calls?

Comment: That should work. What version of RSpec are you using? Try calling the stubed methods in sequence from the spec (Bandmate.create(...:user_id => @user.id...); Bandmate.create(...:user_id => "2222"...); ...) and see if it works.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Multiple expectations are not a problem at all.  What you're running into are ordering problems, given your specific args on unordered expectations.  Check [this page](http://rspec.info/documentation/3.3/rspec-mocks/#Ordering) for details on ordering expectations.

The short story is that you should add `.ordered` to the end of each of your expectations.

Comment: Huh, it's working now even without .ordered  I guess I had a mistake in my code and blamed it on RSpec.

Thanks for the tip!

Comment: link is 404 on github

Comment: Old page has 404. I believe it is this one now: http://rspec.info/documentation/3.3/rspec-mocks/#Ordering

Comment: Thanks @AmitA - I updated the answer with the new link

Answer (score -3):

[Mock Receive Counts](http://rspec.rubyforge.org/rspec/1.1.9/classes/Spec/Mocks.html)

my_mock.should_receive(:sym).once
  my_mock.should_receive(:sym).twice
  my_mock.should_receive(:sym).exactly(n).times
  my_mock.should_receive(:sym).at_least(:once)
  my_mock.should_receive(:sym).at_least(:twice)
  my_mock.should_receive(:sym).at_least(n).times
  my_mock.should_receive(:sym).at_most(:once)
  my_mock.should_receive(:sym).at_most(:twice)
  my_mock.should_receive(:sym).at_most(n).times
  my_mock.should_receive(:sym).any_number_of_times

Works for rspec 2.5 too.

Comment: doesn't cover the different arguments that need to be received for each call.

Comment: how do you do it with different args?